# in double numbers 'round -- how do you understand that?

Tags: meaning, poetry

From a song called [*The Battle of Quebec*](http://www.parolesmania.com/paroles_charbonniers_de_lenfer_les_38777/paroles_le_combat_de_la_danae__the_battle_of_quebec__1123955.html):

> Brave Wolfe drew up his men in a line so pretty
>   On the Plains of Abraham, before the city
>   The French came marching down
>   Arrayed to meet them
>   **In double numbers 'round**, resolved to beat them.

*In double numbers* obviously means that they were twice as many French soldiers as there were British soldiers. But how do you understand the *'round* part?

Comment: My guess is this *'round* is *around* and thus it can mean *about* (in the sense that it's not an exact number).

Comment: This question is going to get a lot of clicks from people who think that it’s related to data types …

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree with DamkerngT and A.Beth that *round* should be understood as *around* (as implied by the editorial spelling *'round*) and suspect that it means that the French, with a much larger force, sought to envelop the British.

However: the fact is you cannot count on *round* here meaning anything in particular. This is not merely poetry but folk poetry—fundamentally **oral** poetry, meaning there is no fixed text but merely a 'skeletal' story in which the only fairly constant element is the rhymes. At least 22 different versions have been published, and probably at least as many recorded.<sup>†</sup>

*Brave Wolfe* (the title under which this piece is usually known) is over 200 years old; it first appears in print sometime before 1813 when Isaiah Thomas (no, not the basketball player!) purchased from a Boston printer a bound collection of some 350 broadsheet ballads which included *Brave Wolfe*. That printer was probably Nathaniel Coverly, since about half the ballads bear his imprint, including that earliest version of *Brave Wolfe*. Coverly's version does not have the word *round* at all at that point; a hasty Google Books search doesn't find it in any printed version before the 20th century; and  some versions field-collected in the 30s and 40s lack it, too.

*Round* seems therefore to be a fairly modern intrusion; and it's easy to see what prompted it. If you look closely at any of the many versions of this song, you will see that many of the couplets are actually quatrains with an ABAB rhyme scheme; for instance:

> He landed at Que**bec**
>     with all his **party**
>   The city to at**tack**
>     being brave and **hearty**

At some point in the last 100 years or so some performer added *round* to the *double number* couplet, to sustain that internal rhyme:

> The French came marching **down**
>     arrayed to **meet them**
>   In double numbers **'round**,
>     resolved to **beat them**.<sup>‡</sup>

But what exactly he *meant* is conjecture. The important thing is it **sounds** good.<sup>‡</sup>

---

<sup>†</sup> <sub>Note that this song, which is widely known in the US and Canada, is an entirely different piece from the song of the same name which is just as widely known in England. Martin Carty has recorded both, and you may see representative lyrics of both songs [here](http://mainlynorfolk.info/watersons/songs/bravewolfe.html).</sub>

<sup>‡</sup> <sub>The same thing has happened to the little dialogue between Wolfe and his aide. In early versions it runs like this:</sub>

> <sub>She’ll fall into our hands, with all her **treasure**.</sub>
>   <sub>O then reply’d brave Wolf, I die with **pleasure**.</sub>

<sub>A variant replaces the first of these lines with *His aide-de-camp replied It's ending in our favour*. But  starting in the 1960s recorded versions employ a different couplet, with a different end rhyme</sub>

> <sub>Quebec is all our own none can **prevent it**</sub>
>   <sub>Oh then, replies bold Wolfe, I die **contented**</sub>

<sub>Most interesting is a version recorded by Tom Kines, which changes  the first part of the second line to create an internal rhyme in the same way *round* does in the *double numbers* line:</sub>

> <sub>Quebec is all our **own** none can **prevent it**</sub>
>   <sub>He said without a **groan**, I die **contented**</sub>

Comment: Is what the performer meant really all that relevant? I understand the question to be about what **'round** _means_ in the English conventions of the day. _Non?_

Comment: @BenKovitz Well, me and A.Beth agree that we understand it as *around* and that the context suggests one force *surrounding* the other. My little essay is intended to point out that there are reasons beyond meaning for a word's presence.

Comment: Ah, well I certainly concur, both with the interpretation as surrounding the British and the principle that the word-choice addresses pressures that have nothing to do with its meaning. As if that weren't enough, a +1 for pointing out the internal rhyme! (Where standards for rhyming are lower—yet another factor having nothing to do with meaning.)

Answer (score 4):

With the apostrophe at *'round*, that pretty well guarantees that it means "around." This being poetry, it can be a little tricky. It could mean "about," as Damkerng T suggests in the comments there, or it could mean "surrounding." Personally, I would suspect "surrounding" -- that the French came down and made a half-circle around Wolfe's army, 'cause there were so many of them.

I could be entirely wrong, though, if "double numbers" doesn't mean "twice as many as Wolfe's army," but means some other army thing -- or some *French* thing, as I see that this is a translation! A translation of poetry is *even trickier* to explain, as the translator may make some interesting linguistic contortions to come up with a line that is A: close to what the original line was, and B: tries to be poetic itself.

Edit: I am informed that the poem -- as should not surprise me, considering Canada -- is in *both* languages, switching back and forth, and the stanzas aren't translations of each other. So at least there's not that trickiness. (It's still poetry, though, and may use words in unusual ways to keep to the poetical forms.)

EDIT TWICE: I forgot to mention that in British English, the word "round" will often mean "around," but *not* have the apostrophe. E.g., American English would write: "We went all 'round Robin Hood's barn" (a term for going a long and winding way to a place), while British English would write: "We went all round Robin Hood's barn," and you just have to know that's "around" from the context. (When I was doing editing, one of my best writers was from England, so I got to learn a *lot* of the quirks of grammar, spelling, and punctuation that are not shared between the countries.)

Comment: I'd be surprised to learn it's a translation; the Québécois would hardly have adopted a song celebrating a French defeat! But the song is so widely known I can easily see them *adapting* it. I'd be interested to see a pointer to a French version.

Comment: I edited my comment -- I don't speak French and didn't look hard enough for cognates. (Headache + small font + eye issues = not a thorough lookover.) Apparently the poem/song alternates languages for stanzas.

Comment: I am stupid - I just realized the link is in the question. The recording is a 'dialogue' between an English folksong and a French one. The French song tells of the capture, in the same year as the Battle of Quebec, of the French frigate La Danaé by the British frigate Southampton. The French vessel fought so heroically that when she was purchased into the British Navy the Admiralty permitted her to keep her name. In the final verse the captured seamen grumble "You impudent English could at least let us go home!"